# Options for SATA ports on motherboard for Files server

Tags: motherboard, windows-server-2008, sata, nas, freenas

I am planning to build a big file server. (Windows or FreeNAS).

I need at lease 300T of space. what options do I have to RAID all disks together?

I mean on physical level what kind of connection topology can I use? what kind of devices support such huge amount of disks? It is not something that you only need 8 or 10 SATA ports on motherboard then you can just do a RAID, it must be some kind of special devices, right?

I am still doing research on this, anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  300TB is not realistic without more information.

Comment: Why isn't this realistic?  You can have 100+ drives show up on a single Linux box using RAID cards?

Comment: It isn't something you can generally 'just' whip up randomly. The backblaze pods are a good example of a 'homebrew' nas setup for massive storage. There's other aspects as well - for example choosing what filesystem to use, how to expose it to users both in terms of your protocols (eg, iScsi) and how you choose to handle the inevitable hard drive failures. This is one of those situations where, at this scale, it pays to hire a professional rather than homebrewing it. While the backblaze pods are a glorious and rather beautiful hack, the fact that you need to shut down a pod to replace disks

Comment: May be an issue. At this point, get quote on a proper san array, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

300Terabytes of storage space?  You'll need some enterprise grade equipment to reach that goal.

Lets say your using 3TB drives (best price/capacity ratio right now), so that's 100 drives.  Even if you did something like a Backblaze storage pod you'd still need 3 pods.  You could also try a JBOD array.  Something like [THIS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=CK3agZSakLwCFQxqfgodvBQAqw&Item=N82E16811152143&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Server%20Chassis-_-N82E16811152143&ef_id=UTlVjAAABBjzu2OM:20140121212434:s), but you'd still need several of those and an enterprise RAID card and storage server.

Comment: I believe you mean that would be 100 drives when using 3TB drives. But otherwise yea, that's a whole heckuvalot of storage and will require very high-end equipment.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my math error.  It's been a long day and simple multiplication was beyond my ability I guess.